# css newbie looking for a more elegant css solution to indent text

Tags: css

I have the following css class:

```
#header h1 {
   float:left;
   font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
   font-size: 2.5em;
   margin-top: 8px;
   margin-left: 0.8em;
   padding-left: 40px;
   background: url("h1bkgrnd.png") no-repeat left center;
   height: 100px;
}
```

And this html:

```
 <div id="header">
   <h1><br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Our Services</h1>
</div>
```

it works fine, but as you can see, I have a bunch of `&nbsp;` to push the text to the right. Otherwise, it sits on top of the picture. 
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want the picture to be part of the flow of the document use an `<img>` tag instead of a background image with CSS

Comment: you really shouldn't have the `<br>` components in your `<h1>`. if you want it a distance from the top, use margins or padding appropriately.

Comment: Can't you just give it more padding?

Comment: From the responses you're giving, its clear that what you're looking for is more than just indenting text (see: [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).  http://cssdeck.com/labs/ybwmvl1d

Comment: ok thanks cimmanon. i'll keep that in mind for my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
#header h1 {
    padding-left: 20px; /*Or according with the picture size you have*/
}
```

Must work.

Answer (score 8):

Unsurprisingly, to indent text you should use the [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) CSS property.

```
#header h1 {
  text-indent: 1em;
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work?  Because it looks like it works to me:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/vn8ewsh7

Comment: meagar... i lied.  your way does work too.  but i realize why my brain defaulted to "that doesn't work" is because I wasn't able to find a way to push the text down without affecting the image.  the <P> tag gives me the ability to control both.  but i've marked your answer as useful!  thanks!!

Comment: @dot Don't do that. Putting a `<p>` inside your `<h1>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: meager if i don't use the <p> tag, what's the best way to push the text down (like a margin-top) without affecting the img?  i am limited in what I can do because I cannot actually change the html. i have to accomplish everything via css.  otherwise, i'd just add an <img> element

Comment: the html is a part of a template library which i'm not allowed to change.  I'm just creating a "skin" if you will...

Comment: What are you *talking about*? You just said you can do it by adding a `<p>` tag, so obviously you *can* modify the markup. The solution here is to take the image out of the `<h1>`, put it in an `<img>` tag, and give them both the same parent container.

Comment: meagar. sorry, i understand i wasn't clear enough in my last comment.  there are some elements I may be able to get away with adding to this template html.  like <p> tags... but <img> would have a much bigger impact. hopefully, that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices, but `text-indent` seems the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what are you trying to indent, are you indenting from another element or from another text.

```
p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

p {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

Comment: this worked.  i added a p tag inside h1... and then used the text indent.  and its happy

Comment: @dot Why would you do that?  The other answers do not require additional markup.

Comment: You can control the top margin on the h1 as well...  This is the *least elegant* solution.

Comment: This is semantically broken. You shouldn't be putting a `<p>` *inside* your `<h1>`, that's not even valid HTML.

Comment: I agree with cimmanon i wouldnt use p, it was an example, you could easily use it with h1

Comment: Again! This was an example, an example is only to assist people in creating there own code.

Comment: @Cam Except for the part where margin isn't going to help here.  The OP wants to shift the text so that it isn't overlapping the background image.  Christian's answer (to use padding) is the next correct solution after meagar's.

Comment: thanks for clarifying things throughout the post cimmanon.  I will stick to the padding left solution... i guess it's the most elegant, for what I'm trying to do

Comment: Just dont add a background, because you will see issues at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Separating out the image in an image tag looks like the best option if you do not really want the image to be in the background of the text.

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/100"/>
<h1>Our Services</h1>
```

CSS:

```
img{
 float:left;
 width:50px;
 height: 50px;
}

h1{
 padding-left: 60px;
}
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/xixebfxw.
In this case, I had to re-size the image by giving appropriate width and height as the text! Also 
margin-left also can be used alternatively for padding-left.

And if the spacing is not a matter of concern and you just need to place the text to the right and image in the left without removing the image as the the background, you can do: http://cssdeck.com/labs/wml9occf But this may not be the best option.